Akkusativ bzw Nominativ in einem Relativsatz
Mein Sohn fragt:
Was du siehst, ist ein Mann, der einen Hut trägt.
Bzw.
Was du siehst, ist einen Mann, der einen Hut trägt.
Meine Erklärung (Ellipse...) gefällt ihm nicht bzw ist vielleicht nicht 100% richtig.
Habt ihr eine gute?
Danke!

Forms of "sein" always take two nominative complements. There is no circumstance in which "ist" occurs with an accusative, no matter how complex the sentence structure.


"Du siehst [einen Mann, [der einen Hut trägt]]" - hier hat das Verb "sehen" als Akkusativobjekt den zusammengesetzten Ausdruck "einen Mann etc"; im Inneren des Objekts gibt es einen Relativsatz. (Der Relativsatz könnte auch abgetrennt im Nachfeld sein, das ist an der Wortfolge nicht ablesbar und ändert nichts an der Argumentation).

"[Was du siehst] ist [ein Mann der einen Hut trägt]" - Hier ist "was" das Akkusativobjekt zu "sehen". Das ganze ist aber tiefer eingebettet. Der Gesamtsatz ist eine Kopulakonstruktion, die vom Verb "ist" abhängt. Der Nebensatz "was du siehst" (ein sog. freier Relativsatz) fungiert als Subjekt dieser Konstruktion, trägt als ganzer aber kein sichtbares Kasusmerkmal. Der andere Teil "ein Mann, der einen Hut trägt" hat als Kasus einen sog. Gleichsetzungs-Nominativ. (Das ist die Kasusregel für Kopulakonstruktionen, genauso wie in "Er ist ein guter Vater).


Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativsatz#Bezug:_attributive_und_freie_Relativs%C3%A4tze
